# /usr/bin/ld cannot find no such file or directory

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to run a mysql client program in c++. The program is executed in a raspberry running in raspbian.

```
g++ -o essaiP -I/home/pi/mysql -I/home/pi/mysql/include -Wl, -Bdynamic essaiP.cpp -lmysqlcppconn
```

It's giving me this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld : cannot find : No such file or directory collect2:error
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: No space inbetween `-Wl,-Bdynamic`

Comment: @Mat Thanks a lot Mat, problem solved !